# C# proxy at webbrowser object

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to create a program in C# that goes to a website, with the use of a proxy server.
If I run this program I got error at line 37 when I debug it. Can you help me please?
I always got the error that the time is occuperd. I changed TimeOut, but 
It never does anything.

txtUrl is a textbox where you need to put in the url of the website you wanna visite.
txtProxyPath is a textbox that is used as a openfiledialog, 
and there I can select a .txt file with proxy ips in.

Here the code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YoutubeRefresh
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static private ArrayList listProxy = new ArrayList();
        static private short proxyShort = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uriAdress = new Uri(txtUrl.Text);
            object[] arrayProxy = listProxy.ToArray();
            WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy(arrayProxy[proxyShort].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Proxyserver used: " + arrayProxy[proxyShort].ToString());
            proxyShort += 1;
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
            webRequest.Proxy = proxyObject;


            // httpwepresponse error
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream; 
        }

        private void btnChoosListProxy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtProxyPath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }

            foreach (var v in File.ReadAllLines(txtProxyPath.Text))
            {
                listProxy.Add(v.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: *I got error at line 37*,  Wait, I am trying to count the lines

Comment: HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
There is a comment above: httpwebsresponse error
The line under it is what the debugger marks at debugging

Comment: It's probably an error with the proxy. Did you try the same proxy in a web browser on the same machine?

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: @aKzenT Yes I've tried it on my computer and L.B. I got the time out error

Comment: What I and probably @L.B are wondering about is the EXACT error message. The complete text and exception type. There are many "time out errors" but they could result from various sources inside the framework. So it's always important to post the exact error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("IP", port);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Also in your App.Config file, (if you don't have one, create one) add the following.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which .Net versions? Any references about the bug?

Comment: I'm really sorry @Aydin Adn, but I cant find where can I accept it, where does it stand.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

"To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"

Comment: @user3076115 what was the content of `arrayProxy[proxyShort].ToString()` in your question and how do you construct a WebProxy now. Your accepted answer doesn't seem to do something useful.